# Nullable initialized to null - understanding the source code

Tags: c#, null, nullable

I was looking at the following code for the .NET `Nullable<T>` class:  http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs,ffebe438fd9cbf0e

And I was wondering, what would be its behavior for the following use:

`int? x = null;`

Obviously, `x.hasValue()` returns `false`, however I see that in the constructor, `hasValue` property is always set to `true`.

So what am I missing?

Comment: Since there's no value the default constructor will be called which initialises `hasValue` to its default value of `false`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"the constructor", yes, the constructor that is explicitly written for `Nullable<T>`, however all structs have one additional constructor, a parameterless default constructor that you're not allowed to implement. This will always be present.

So you can think of the code from your question as similar to this:

```
int? x = new Nullable<int>();
```

In fact, if we compile your code and my code and look at the generated IL:

Your code:

```
IL_0001:  ldloca.s    00 // a
IL_0003:  initobj     System.Nullable<System.Int32>
```

My code:

```
IL_0001:  ldloca.s    00 // a
IL_0003:  initobj     System.Nullable<System.Int32>
```

So they're completely identical.

The default constructor for a struct initializes all fields to byte-wise zeroes, which equates to false for bool fields, 0 for number fields, `null` for reference type fields, etc.

Comment: Not to be confused with `int? x = default` which assigns the default value of nullables which in turn is `null`. Took me a moment to realize the difference when reading the [MS lesson about nullability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/csharp-null-safety/2-understand-nullability).

Comment: @Johnson I believe at the IL level, that will be indistinguishable from `int? x = new Nullable<int>();` and indeed, [Sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxFANgHwAICYCMBYAKAwGYACbUgYRQgGdbSBvQ018nANnIBZSBBABQBKFm2YE2k0rAQB+UgA9SAXlIwApgHdSAOQCuKGsBTqAPDIB8wgNyippAOKUAdAGl16gA58UUAG7qAgpCthJsAL527FwYvABCwlHi9qwy8kqqACbqAGYQBgihKY4u7l4+/oHBRRFRGJw8VIlhrMkpaYoqagYoNfZObh7evgFBIVGRBOFAA===) seems to agree.

Comment: From the last part of your answer, I expected `new Nullable<int>()` to result in `x` being `0`,  as I interpreted this call to execute the default constructor of structs you described (unfortunately, I was neglecting your discussion of IL similarity above at that point). Now I see that only `int? x = new()` seems to call the default struct constructor and lead to `x=0`. I thought `new()` is just the (target-typed form)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/new-operator#target-typed-new] of `new Nullable<int>()` in this case. Why is the outcome different?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288208%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> Structs cannot contain explicit parameterless constructors. Struct members are automatically initialized to their default values.

That means there is always a 'default parameterless constructor'. You don't see it, but it is always there. If you pass in a value for `T` (which isn't nullable), the constructor can assume it has a value.

Try for example this one:

```
Nullable<int> c = new Nullable<int>();
Console.WriteLine(c.HasValue); // false

c = new Nullable<int>(1);
Console.WriteLine(c.HasValue); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

Nullable types are treated in a special way by C#, not like regular `struct`s.

It's not possible to assign a `null` to a regular `struct` variable, but it's possible to assign it to a `Nullable<T>` variable. Why? It's described in C# language specification, section 6.1.5

> 6.1.5 Null literal conversions
>
> An implicit conversion exists from the null literal to any nullable type. This conversion produces the null value (§4.1.10) of the given nullable type.

The compiler implements this conversion as a call to the default parameterless constructor of `Nullable<T>`. Every `struct` has an implicit parameterless constructor, which initializes all fields to their default values. The default value of `bool` is `false`.